# JProfiler jpcontroller is not working even while i'm profiling with GUI

Tags: tomcat, jvm, jprofiler

I want to profile an application server on a tomcat and also have command line access to it!
so I first used *JProfiler GUI* to connect to it and even done some profiling with it and it worked fine. 
Now without detaching the profiler I used `jpcontoroller.exe` with out any parameter and it found the profiled jvm and tries to connect to it but it can't connect. Here's the output:

```
Connecting to org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start [3956] ...
Starting JMX management agent ...
JProfiler MBean not found. Waiting for 20 seconds.
....................
ERROR: The JProfiler MBean was not registered in the profiled JVM
Maybe the JVM has been started with the "nowait" option and has never been
connected to by a JProfiler GUI
```

And it finally can't connect!

It happens while I am profiling using GUI! so it's for sure connected. Can any body help? Note that this same scenario does works for a *hello world* java program! and even for a tomcat on another place but not here!
 I don't know why! is there any thing that I should check? I've already tried to start tomcat with `JProfiler` itself but it didn't help!

Comment: Did you attach with the GUI or was the JVM profiled at startup? That could make a different with respect to the MBean server.

Comment: Actually I tried both but none of them worked!

Comment: Try connecting with jconsole to see if there is an MBean server running.

Comment: Thanks! I connected using jconsole and found no Jprofiler MBean there no how can i solve it? note that I already have the same version in another place and every thing works there (I found the MBean there too).

Comment: OK, so the JProfiler agent creates its own MBean server while there is another MBean server that it should use. Did you specify the VM parameter -Djprofiler.jmxServerPort= ...? If yes, please remove it. Instead, add the VM parameter -Djprofiler.mBeanDelay=30. This means that the agent will only try to register the MBean after 30 seconds, so the other MBean server should be running at that point. This applies to the profiling mode where you specify the -agentpath VM parameter at startup (not in attach mode).

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid you didn't get me! there is no MBean There! JProfiler doesn't even create it's own MBean server and there is no MBean related to JProfiler either.

Comment: There can be multiple MBean servers. The question is which MBean server is exposed by the JMXConnectorServer.